# Weird redirects

Tags: browser, virus, virus-removal, adware

We are getting a weird redirct from black-face.com (which I needed for a school assignment) to some other pages always flashing through zeroredirct1 (dot) com. On other computers, it happens for other sites too.

Our network runs from a netgear r7000

It is happening on

- Android 5.1 Nexus 6 on both data and our WiFi network
- OSx El Capitan on our WiFi network
- iOS iPad 9.1 on our WiFi network
- Windows 10 on our WiFi Network

Deleting caches and cookies seems to only be a temporary fix as it comes back within about a day. We tried changing the DNS on our router to Google's public DNS. This may have solved it, at least temporarily, as for right now, it is going to the correct site but not sure how we get rid of it entirely.

It has not changed our default homepage. I don't think it is rooted in an extension (although it may be) because it is also happening on mobile devices which don't support them. All firmware and OS software are up to date.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: ". This may have solved it, at least temporarily, but not sure how we get rid of it entirely" - I don't understand.  Did this get rid of it or not?

Comment: @Ramhound We just did that right before posting this. So for now, it isn't being redirected but I am afraid there is still a virus of sorts or that it will come back.

Comment: The problems exists across multiple operating systems, if anything, its the router that infected.  Reset it if you truly believe that to be the case.

Comment: @Ramhound but the problem occured for me on my phone when connected with data. So what does that mean?

Comment: Reset the phone if you believe that tot be the case.

Answer (score -1):

It's malware on your computer(s), plain and simple. See here: http://www.anvisoft.com/resources/how-to-remove-za-zeroredirect1-com-popups-adware-removal-guide/

Comment: So then what about the phone and iPad? Also whoever down voted, why?

Comment: I don't think this kind of malware (zeroredirect1) exists for phones, so I can't explain how you can see it on a phone that's connected directly using mobile data. That is quite curious.