# Weird redirect through zeroredirect1

Tags: browser, anti-virus, adware

When I go to black-face.com (for a school assignment) it has been redirecting me to zeroredirect1 (dot) com. However it seems to only happen on some devices. On some computers it happens on other websites too.

- Android 5.1 on data and our WiFi Network
- osX El Capitan on our WiFi Network
- iOS 9.1 on an iPad on our WiFi Network
- Windows 10 on our WiFi network

Our network is running from a Netgear R7000.

All firmware and software is up to date on all devices.

Clearing the cache and cookies seems to only be a temporary fix as it comes back the next day. Changing the DNS to Google's public DNS may have worked but we want to get rid of this virus completely.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird redirects](http://superuser.com/questions/997765/weird-redirects)

Comment: Yes sorry. Didn't realize they both got posted. I will delete one.